# After showing div, function onsubmit is hiding div again

Tags: javascript

I created a very simple function to show a div after submitting a form. It works for a second, but then the div gets hidden again.

Someone could help me realize the reason?

The js call:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="generator-form" onsubmit="showHide()">
```

The js:

```
function showHide() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle of it?

Comment: If your div is hidden by default, and your form submission refreshes the page, then it will be hidden of course.

Comment: Is something else hiding the `div`? How did it get hidden on the first place? Is it being re-rendered by a library, does it start hidden on page load? Creating a fiddle as @Siddharth suggests would help isolate and understand the problem

Comment: yes, just a moment

Comment: here, I made a code pen http://codepen.io/biibis/pen/BWxzJa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="generator-form" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">
```

Your page is refreshed, that's why it appears again.